# Copy string from file to file until one character is found in Python

Tags: python, string, loops, search

I have got two text files. I want to read text 1 and look for a string "example", when this string is found I want to copy it together with the next characters until the character "A" is found. For example:
Content in text1.txt: "jnajsndneuinnuincuiewexampleohelloAhyhakjs"
Content copied in text2.txt: "ejemplohello"
The thing is text1 will keep growing and I have to do this task in a loop, so, another restriction is that the second time "example" appears I have to save the second string after it, not the first one ("hello"). Example:

Content in text1.txt:

```
"jnajsndneuinnuincuiewexampleohelloAhyhakjsexamplegoodbyeAhjuheui"
```

Content copied in text2.txt:

```
"ejemplohelloexamplegoodbye"
```

Any idea of how to do this in Python?

I have tried this code, but it does not work as I want and it does not work once the string has been found one time:

```
def detect(k):
   string = "example"
   with open("tex1.txt", "r") as f:
      content = f.read()
      if string in content:
         with open("text2.txt", "a+") as f:
            if (character != "A"): 
               f.write(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def detect():
    string = "example"
    with open("tex1.txt", "r") as source_file:
      content = source_file.read()
      x = re.split(string, content)
      with open("text2.txt", "a+") as f:
          for index in range(len(x)):
              if index == 0:
                  pass
              else:
                  f.write(string)
                  for char in x[index]:
                      if char == 'A':
                          break
                      else:
                          f.write(char)
```

re.split will split the entire content from the desired string and store them in a list after that in the outer for loop the initial element of x will be the content before the desired string so it will be passed, the other elements will be processed in the inner loop character by character before reaching "A" in this case.

Comment: It does not work as I want. I dont want to get this output "exampleexamplehexampleheexamplehelexamplehellexamplehello", I want "examplehello". Whatsmore, it continues saving in file 2 all the content that is being added to file 1 after the first detection